# I'm nonsense, or I'm made of clay

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> My start sheds tears somewhat expressly
>   My end was sung by Elvis Presley
>   My middle is a fabled bird of prey
>   I'm nonsense, or I'm made of clay

Who or what am I?

Comment: Maybe "My start is made of Chromium" instead, for future reference? The elemental symbol for Chromium is Cr :)

Comment: @DoktorJ sure, that would work too. Personally, I much prefer clueing with dictionary words instead of arbitrary letter combinations, whenever there’s a choice between the two.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

My start sheds tears somewhat expressly

> Still on it... perhaps it is Cry (shed tears) without the Y (why as an expression?) 
>  Or as [M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63747/im-nonsense-or-im-made-of-clay/63749#comment193707_63749) suggested: [Croc(odile tears)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocodile_tears)!

My end was sung by Elvis Presley

> Rock (music genre)

My middle is a fabled bird of prey

> Roc (giant mythological bird)

I'm nonsense, or I'm made of clay

> Crock ( An earthenware vessel. or another word for 'foolish talk')

Comment: Yep, that must be it. As for the start, [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocodile_tears).

Comment: @MOehm, Thank you, that sounds much better. I'll add it.

Comment: Congrats on the mortarboard! This is, of course, the correct answer.